# Wrong encoding of file name with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, encoding

I have a Spring MVC handler method, that returns file `čšľ.csv`, but the file name comes wrongly encoded - I get `___.csv` in Chrome, or `???.csv` in Postman.

The code can be seen here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class EncodingsandboxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EncodingsandboxApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/",
            produces = {"text/csv"},
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getExample() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(new MediaType("text", "plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=čšľ.csv")
                .build();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get response with Content-Disposition header to be `attachment; filename=čšľ.csv`, but I've just got `attachment; filename=???.csv` (with Postman).

Why is that and how can I get correctly encoded filename?

I thought the "UTF_8" in `contentType(new MediaType("text", "plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` will do the trick, but it won't. I've tried url encoded the filename (like this: `"attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode("čšľ.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`), but I've just got literal url encoded filename.

I also checked `spring.http.encoding.charset`, but UTF-8 is default here.

My version of Spring boot is 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

You were almost correct, you forgot to include a `*` after `filename`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = {"text/csv"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getExample() throws Exception {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(new MediaType("text", "plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=" + URLEncoder.encode("čšľ.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
            .build();
}
```

Some examples can be found in [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987)

Comment: The `*` being a suffix for "extended" parameters with extra charset capabilities.

Comment: It's works, but the RFC also requires you to specify an encoding, e.g. `*=UTF-8''`

Answer (score 0):

You want to encode the filename such that when you upload it, and later download it, you want to be able to find the same file from the file name.
To do this, you can use URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes.

```
String  fileName = URLEncoder.encode("čšľ.csv", "UTF-8");`
```

Comment: I don't get it - I'm not uploading anything. I'm just requesting a file from the Spring MVC handler method. I've tried URLEncoder as can be seen in my question, but with no effect.